# Why ipv6 address already there before DHCP?

Tags: networking, wireshark, ipv6, dhcp

According to an ipv6 dhcp log (Wireshark) example:

https://packetpushers.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/dhcpv6_2.jpg

We can see the client's ipv6 address already there before doing DHCP (S.A.R.R.)

because protocol allowed it ? just do a confirmation with DHCP server to keep the existed ipv6 address?

Comment: when checking ipv4 dhcp behavior, we can see client ip is 0.0.0.0 first, but the ipv6 seems not, what's the difference ?

Comment: Every IPv6 interface will have a link-local address in the `fe80::/10` address range. IPv6 will normally have at least two addresses, the link-local address and a global address (in the `2000::/3` global address range). An interface can actually have multiple global addresses, and maybe one or more ULA addresses (in the `fc00::/7` address range), too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPv6 hosts may automatically generate IP addresses internally using stateless address autoconfiguration (SLAAC), or they may be assigned configuration data with DHCPv6.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCPv6